# How to prefix string to the file at the starting location in a file?

Tags: java, jboss, drools

I have file as below.

```
  rule "IC-86"
    agenda-group "commonATSP"
    dialect "mvel"
    when
        eval($count > 10)
    then
        modify( $attribute ){ $imageVersion,$attributes.get(),imageName };
end
```

I need to prefix the below mentioned string at the top of the file.

```
import java.lang.Exception;
```

The output should looks like as below.

```
  import java.lang.Exception;
  rule "IC-86"
        agenda-group "commonATSP"
        dialect "mvel"
        when
            eval($count > 10)
        then
            modify( $attribute ){ $imageVersion,$attributes.get(),imageName };
    end
```

Please provide me some pointers to implement the same using Java.

Comment: You actually are the maintainer of the Drools file or you are getting it from another party and cannot modify it? To wit, is there any reason you simply can't modify the DRL to include the import?

Comment: why java? it can be achieved simply with a single bash line

Comment: i am generating the drl file from BRL after generating the drl i need to add corresponding imports.

Answer (score 0):

This method prepends a **CharSequence** to the beginning of a file which is what I think you're looking for.

```
/**
 * Prepends a string value to the beginning of a file
 * @param prepend The prepended value
 * @param addEol If true, appends an EOL character to the prepend
 * @param fileName The file name to prepend to
 */
public static void prependToFile(CharSequence prepend, boolean addEol, String fileName) {
    if(prepend==null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Passed prepend was null", new Throwable());
    if(fileName==null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Passed fileName was null", new Throwable());
    File f = new File(fileName);
    if(!f.exists() || !f.canRead() || !f.canWrite()) throw new IllegalArgumentException("The file [" + fileName + "] is not accessible", new Throwable());
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    BufferedInputStream bis = null;
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    BufferedOutputStream bos = null;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[8096];
    int bytesRead = 0;
    try {
        baos.write(prepend.toString().getBytes());
        if(addEol) {
            baos.write(System.getProperty("line.separator", "\n").getBytes());
        }
        fis = new FileInputStream(f);
        bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
        while((bytesRead = bis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            baos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        bis.close(); bis = null;
        fis.close(); fis = null;
        fos = new FileOutputStream(f, false);
        bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
        bos.write(baos.toByteArray());          
        bos.close();            
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to prepend to file [" + fileName + "]", e);
    } finally {
        if(bis!=null) try { bis.close(); } catch (Exception e) {}
        if(fis!=null) try { fis.close(); } catch (Exception e) {}
        if(bos!=null) try { bos.close(); } catch (Exception e) {}
        if(fos!=null) try { fos.close(); } catch (Exception e) {}                       
    }       
}
```

Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    prependToFile("import java.lang.Exception;", true, "/tmp/rule.txt");
}
```